# How to provide one-touch access to a PDF file in the cloud with rich features like annotation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

I need to be able to download a PDF file from a location on the Internet and then open it (just the file, not to a specific page) in an app like Goodreader or even iBooks.

What I originally thought was that I would put an icon on my users' home page that launches a PDF file in an app, similar to how in Safari you can "Add To Home Page" and add a link onto the Home Page. The idea would be to have that functionality but with an, e.g.,  ibooks:// link rather than an http:// and it would open the pdf being linked to there within iBooks.

I am able to launch Safari to view a PDF using the Add To Home Page function to put an icon on the Home Page pointing to a PDF at a certain URL, so I am wondering if using, e.g. a Scheme definition I can pull it off.

So my solutions so for are:

1) Create a link to the PDF to open in Safari using "Add To Home Page" (offers zero functionality, including the hard requirement of being able to annotate the PDF)

2) Employ a specific App's Custom URL Scheme Definiton with the iPhone Configuration Utility's "Web Clips" create something to the effect of *ibooks://www.pdf.com/document.pdf* (i dont think this works)

3) Write a custom app and figure out how to do the annotating part myself (Did this using FastPDFKit but it does not include anything for annotating which is really key)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put a g infront of the URL when adding to home screen, it will open with GoodReader when launched.